# Excel Solver to maximise by using VBA doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, solver

I'm trying to record a macro by using solver. I'm trying to maximise cell M24, change Cell D8, E8, D13 and E13. D8, E8,D13 and E13 all greater than 0, and F8=D8+E8=1, F13=D13+E13=1. My code is not working. Basically, it's not changing any values in cells D8, E8, D13 and E13 at all? Could someone please point out where I did wrong?

```
Sub SolverMacro1()
'
' SolverMacro1 Macro
'

        Worksheets("Optimise").Activate

        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$8", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$8", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$8", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$13", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$13", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$13", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"


        SolverOk SetCell:="$M$24", MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:="$D$8:$E$8 & $D$13:$E$13"

        SolverSolve

End Sub
```

Many thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of the `ByChange` parameter that you pass to `SolverOk` to `"$D$8:$E$8,$D$13:$E$13"`.  You might also want to call `SolverReset` after activating the worksheet but before calling the other Solver procedures.

Comment: What happens when you run the macro?  Does the "Solver Results" dialog appear?  After you run the macro, if you open Solver manually (using the menus), does the "Solver Parameters" dialog show what you would expect?

Comment: Hi Brain, after I ran the macro, the dialog appears asks if want to save solver values or keep original, but nothing changes in the cells... it's very strange. Another strange thing is, I had formula for E8=1-D8 and E13=1-D13, after running macro, all formula disappears, only original values left. Yes, after running macro, when i open solver manually, the parameters are what I set for the codes above.

Comment: The changes don't show up (at least for me) until, after the "Solver Results" dialog appears, you choose "Keep Solver Solution" and choose OK.  Did you try this?

Comment: Why do you have formulas in cells E8 and E13?  Try removing them, as the constraints you place on cells F8 and F13 should suffice.  Is it possible that the initial values of the cells gives the optimal solution?  If so, they might not appear to change.